# Set Multiple datadetector types for UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITextview and I want to enable 2 different datadetector modes for this textView. I know, I can set the datadetectorTypes to 'UIDataDetectorTypeAll' but that enables the linkage to some of the unwanted data types too (e.g. Address or time). Is there anyway where I can specify more than one datadetector type to my textView without using the 'UIDataDetectorTypeAll' option?

Obaid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes , with | between them.  Like this:

`[textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber]`

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the solution in Swift

`textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.link, .phoneNumber]`